# Matching with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that matches a certain patter, here's an example:
test against

```
fiction <a href="/wiki/Canon_(fiction)">Canon</a> some more fiction text
```

what's required is to match all "fiction" words without matching the ones in `<a>` tags.

I've attempted to do it with

```
/((fiction)(?!<a href=.*fiction.*">))/g
```

however it still matches the one in the anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden HTML node and preserve all of the text nodes. Using a regular expression is a bad idea. Navigating the DOM is the safest way.

```js
var htmlText = 'fiction <a href="/wiki/Canon_(fiction)">Canon</a> some more fiction text';
var HIDDEN_CLASS_NAME = 'hidden-word-list';

console.log(extractWords(htmlText).join(', '));

function extractWords(htmlText) {
  createHiddenNode(HIDDEN_CLASS_NAME, htmlText, document.body);
  var tmpNode = document.getElementsByClassName(HIDDEN_CLASS_NAME)[0];
  var words = grabTextFromNode(tmpNode);
  tmpNode.remove();
  return words;
}
function createHiddenNode(className, htmlText, targetEl) {
  var tempEl = document.createElement('div');
  tempEl.className = className;
  tempEl.innerHTML = htmlText;
  tempEl.style.display = 'none';
  if (targetEl != null) {
    targetEl.appendChild(createHiddenNode(HIDDEN_CLASS_NAME, htmlText));
  }
  return tempEl
}
function grabTextFromNode(node) {
  var words = [];
  if (node != null) {
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node != null) {
      if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        words.push(node.textContent);
      }
      node = node.nextSibling;
    }
  }
  words = words.join(' ').split(/\s+/);
  return words;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```